# R memory puzzle on ECDF environments

Tags: r, memory, ecdf

I have a massive list of ECDF objects.

Similar to:

```
vals <- rnorm(10000)
x <- ecdf(vals)
ecdfList <- lapply(1:10000, function(i) ecdf(vals))
save(ecdfList, file='mylist.rda')

class(ecdfList[[1]])
[1] "ecdf"     "stepfun"  "function"
```

Let's quit the R server and start fresh.

```
q()
> R  (I'm on a server running ubuntu, R 3.4.4)
```

Now, the problem is, when starting with a fresh env,
loading and deleting the ecdfList doesn't free the memory.

```
load('mylist.rda')
rm(ecdfList)
gc()
```

top and free still show the memory as being used by R.

So I thought I would be clever and load them to a new environment.

```
e = new.env()
load('mylist.rda', envir=e)
rm(e)
gc()
```

But, same thing happens. top and free still show the memory as being used.

Where are those ecdf objects?  How can I safely remove that list of ecdfs from memory?

Maybe the memory is just being held.. just in case.. by R? This doesn't happen with other data objects.

Here's an example of watching the memory with 'free'.

From Rstudio, I'll create a list of vectors and then release them, checking the memory used before and after.

```
dave@yoga:~$ free
                        total        used        free      shared
available Mem:       16166812     1548680    11725452      932416
```

Then make a list of vectors.

```
x <- lapply(1:10000, function(a) rnorm(n=10000))
```

Then check the free memory.

```
davidgibbs@gibbs-yoga:~$ free
                        total        used        free      shared 
available Mem:       16166812     2330068    10954372      921956
```

From within Rstudio, rm the vectors.

```
rm(x)
gc()
```

Check the memory again,

```
davidgibbs@gibbs-yoga:~$ free
                           total        used        free      shared
available    Mem:       16166812     1523252    11750620      932528
```

OK, so the memory is returned.

Now we'll try it with a list of ECDFs.

```
# already saved the list as above
e = new.env()
open('mylist.rda', envir=e)
```

And check the memory

```
dave@yoga:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared 
Mem:       16166812     1752808    10213168     1166136 


e <- new.env()
load('ecdflist.rda', envir = e)
```

And we'll check the memory

```
dave@yoga:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared 
Mem:       16166812     3365536     8667616     1096236
```

Now we'll rm that env.

```
rm(e)
gc()
```

Final memory check.

```
dave@yoga:~$ free
                        total        used        free      shared    
available Mem:       16166812     3321584     8726964
```

And still being used until we reset R.

Thank you!!
 -dave

Comment: Just for completeness, could you also include an example where it doesn't happen with other data objects? And maybe show the `top` and `free` commands you're running and the relevant parts of their output?

Comment: OK, that should do it. Thanks!